# why can we use proper javascript condition inside for loop standard condition

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

```js
for(a = [], b = 5; b-- > 0 && 2*c+1 < 5; a.push(2*b+1));
```

is this loop wrong, this follow the standard of for loop
`for(initialization; condition; increment);`

**Edit** consider 2*b +1 as 2*c +1 , i just ask, is this condition is a valid loop condition ?

Comment: `2*b+1 < 5` that is never true because `b=5` and `b--` is in your condition when it should be in increment.

Comment: @zer00ne: indeed, it's pretty weird to mutate counters in the condition part. But _technically_ it is valid code. :shrug:

Comment: It seems that the increment is loop body in disguise. What's going on here? :)

Comment: ooh i got that, sorry for that, but my question is is `b-- > 0 && 2*c +1 && z*1 >0 ` something like this condition is a valid loop condition ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> what is wrong with this loop

Initial value of `b` fails this check.

```
2*b+1 < 5
```

So neither loop body, nor the increment are ever executed.

---

> consider `2*b +1` as `2*c +1`, i just ask, is this condition is a valid loop condition

Yes, you can put any valid javascript expression there. As long as it parses, it's good.